# Kotlin: remove identical adjacent members of an array

Tags: kotlin

If I have the following array:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,3]
```

Is there any built in method in Kotlin which will filter out adjacent elements of the same value, resulting in:

```
[1,2,1,2,3]
```

It's important that the order is preserved.

P.S. My actual use case isn't integers, it's an object which implements equals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard function to do this.
But it is easy to build one with `mapOrNull`:

```
fun <T : Any> Iterable<T>.removeAdjacent(): List<T> {
    var last: T? = null
    return mapNotNull {
        if (it == last) {
            null
        } else {
            last = it
            it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a one-line solution, using `zipWithNext()`:

```
list.zipWithNext().filter{ it.first != it.second }.map{ it.first } + list.last()
```

That creates a list of pairs of adjacent elements; we then filter out the identical pairs, and take the first of each remaining pair.  That will have omitted the last one, so we have to add that in separately.

That works with any element type, using the object's own notion of equality (via its `equals()` method); this includes nullable types (unlike another answer).  And it's stateless so ‘pure’ functional (which you may or may not consider a good thing!).

It handles one-element lists, but not empty lists; for completeness, you'd have to handle those separately.  And it would fit very neatly into an extension function:

```
fun <T> List<T>.compress() = when (isEmpty()) {
    true -> listOf()
    else -> zipWithNext().filter{ it.first != it.second }.map{ it.first } + last()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a clever and interesting way to approach the problem, but I think the accepted answer is more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: You’re assuming the last element doesn’t match the second-to-last element.

Comment: @Tenfour04 No, it handles that case too.  (Try it!)  If the last two are different, then the last pair will be included, giving the penultimate value; then the `last()` will give the last one.  If the last two are the same, the last pair will get filtered out, so you'll only get the single value from `last()`.  Similarly, if the last three are the same, the last two pairs will get filtered out, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Functional solution using `fold`:

```
val result = listOf(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,3)
        .fold(mutableListOf<Int>()) { currentList, currentItem ->

            if (currentList.isEmpty()) { // Applies only to the very first item
                mutableListOf(currentItem)
            } else {

                if (currentItem != currentList.last()) {
                    currentList.apply { add(currentItem) }
                } else {
                    currentList
                }
            }
        }
```